# Use the positions of the values of an array in another array with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, unique

I want to get hold of the positions in an array and want to extract the values in those positions from another array.
I have two arrays:

```
Array_1 = (1, 0, 23, 4, 0, 0, 17, 81, 0, 10)
Array_2 = (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
```

With

```
a, b = numpy.unique(Array_1)
```

I get the following: a contains the values and b the positions.

```
a = (1, 23, 4, 17, 81, 10)
b = (0, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9)
```

I want the values of Array_2 at the positions of Array_1.  In other words, I want:

```
c = (11, 13, 14, 17, 18, 20)
```

How do I get hold of those values?

Comment: There are multiple flaws in your example. 1st) `numpy.unique` will return a *sorted* array of unique values, including the `0`. 2nd) To get the indices of `np.unique`, you have to use the keyword `return_index=True`.

Answer (score 3):

Numpy supports vectorized indexing, see ["Integer array indexing".](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) In practice, this means you can do:

```
a, b = numpy.unique(Array_1, return_index=True)
c = Array_2[b]
```

Comment: You sure this works? It gives me `array([12, 11, 14, 20, 17, 13, 18])`, unless I am doing something wrong at my end.

Comment: @Divakar, I was going by the text in the question, but now I see that the example values in there are weird. In the OP `a` isn't sorted and doesn't include `0`. That's why the order in my answer's output is different and includes `12`.

Comment: It is weird indeed. It seems one can get the output with just `Array_2[Array_1!=0]` too. Not sure what's the significance of `numpy.unique`.

Comment: `np.unique` returns all *unique* values of an array, therefore every value is present only once. `Array_2[Array_1!=0] will evaluate at *all* non-zero values in Array_1, which is something entirely different. BTW: To do this sort of slicing, one would need to convert the tuples to `np.ndarray` first...